# Getting an error saying an expression of non-boolean type specified case sql error

Tags: sql-server

I have the following statement as part of my stored procedure and I am getting an error saying  an expression of non-boolean type specified case sql error
The sql statement is:-

```
AND ( CASE
                WHEN (CONVERT(DATE, Cm_Opt_Tsk_Task_S.Tsk_DUEDATE) <= @EndDate )
                    AND (ISNULL(Cm_Cfg_Tst_TaskStatus_S.Tst_DESCRIPTION, '') IN ('Completed',
                                                                                    'Cancelled',
                                                                                    'Closed',
                                                                                    'Renamed',
                                                                                    'Open',
                                                                                    'Started',
                                                                                    'Pending')) THEN
                    (SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM    Cm_Opt_Tsk_Task_S AS TotalInStandard)
        END )
```

I tried breaking down the statement but I am still getting the error

Comment: That is a fragment not a statement - give an entire statement that produces this error.

Comment: Can you provide the specific error and the whole statement? I'm assuming this is a where clause, in which case you have an object to compare but no comparison.

Comment: Ohh I figure out the error but thanks for the help

Comment: Then this question should be closed @Hitzz91